# Flex 4.6 unable to see Design view mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.6, designview

I was able to view my Design view before, but I think I have done some changes with the SDK. I have set it back to 4.6 but I am unable to see the Design view in mobile projects.

I am able to see it in a regular flex project though.

Any idea on how and what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because may be you've changed your preferences.

Goto Window Menu and select the option - `Enable Design Mode`

Also go in `Preferences` dialog - `Flash Builder` - `Editors` - `Design Mode` and check the option

```
Automatically show design-related views
```